# Control motor DC with buttons

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, motor

i'm new user with Arduino, i want to know if there is a tutorial to control the rotation of a motor like : with 4 buttons, the first to rotate +pi/2 the second to rotate -pi/2 the third to rotate +-pi and the fourth to stop the rotation
thanks a lot !!

Comment: there may be such a tutorial, but you do not need it ..... what you are referring to is not one programming action, it is two actions ..... one is the detection of button presses ..... the other is motor rotation control ..... find tutorials that teach you how to read button presses and how to control the motor .... then you put those two together so that the program does what you want it to do

Comment: Is the motor a stepper? If not you will have trouble getting it to position reliably.

Comment: duncan Thank you for your reply :) ! I do not know yet about the type of engine to choose, I want to run a table with a motor connected to the Arduino board. I think to do it on a stepper motor as you say

Comment: jsotola, thanks for you reply :) , i'll try, i know how works the detection of button presses, i'm learning about rotation control